# Another prefix - suffix - infix mix

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My start shortens round about
>   My ending settles doubt
>   My middle means combined with
>   My whole is always split

Comment: Just a doubt, is it *combined with* or *combine with*?

Comment: It is *combined with*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll take a shot at this  with

> **circumfix**

My start shortens round about:

> *cir* as abbreviation for circa

My middle means combined with:

> *cum*, latin preposition of the intended meaning

My ending settles doubt:

> *fix* in the meaning of to establish, to set definitely. (Thanks to OnlyF I delved deep into Merriam Webster's and rephrased that.)

My whole is always split:

> staying in the theme, a circumfix always consists of two affixes, one placed at the start of a word, one at the end, so it's very literally split.

Comment: Nice one, you got them all first go :) Although there are more definitions of the ending which would make for a bit better fit, I think it's pretty much in the way you've written it down that it seems to not be such a good fit, to *** something can mean to rot13(gb frggyr qrsvavgryl, be chg vagb creznarag sbez), which settles doubt..

Comment: Oh, I got it? Cool. - But if this is the correct answer, it should be marked as such. As far as I can see, it's not marked. Apart from my browser may be playing dumb: Did your mark not get registered, or do you mean that it's still not complete?

Comment: No I was just leaving it for a bit in case you wanted to edit after my comment (not sure if you still can after accepting), but you'll get the tick soon in any case :)

Comment: Ah, OK. Well if you'd prefer that, I'll do.

Comment: That was a nice one, thanks. I liked the hints, and the overall consistency of the theme helps a lot to establish a good feeling for whether an answer fits well or not. So while trying around, there was always a good certainty that I was not quite there yet. Once I had it, it satisfyingly snapped right into place. I like that.